# How to count repeated answers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im doing a online poll, righ now I need to count how many repeated response there is, i want to Display something like this: "**Answer #1 has X votes**" an so on.
Right now my view is the default generated.
My controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Results(Vote vote, Answer answer)
    {
        using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
        {

            var Answer = poolDbContext.Answers.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == a.Id);
            var Question = await poolDbContext.Questions.Include(A => A.Answers).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == r.Id);
            var Vote = poolDbContext.Votes.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == a.Id);
            answer.Votes = poolDbContext.Votes.ToList();

            answer.Text =  Answer.Text;
            answer.QuestionId = Question.Id;
            answer.Id = Answer.Id;
            vote.AnswerId = Answer.Id;
            vote.Id = Vote.Id;
            vote.IpAdress = Vote.IpAdress;
            vote.VoteDate = Vote.VoteDate;

            return View(vote);
        }
    }
```

my Models:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    public Answer()
    {
        Votes = new List<Vote>();
    }
}
public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; }
}
 public class Vote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IpAdress { get; set; }
    public DateTime VoteDate { get; set; }
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: since `answer.Votes` is a list, you could display the output of `answer.Votes.Count()` somewhere on your page (you can write that in the Razor code). However your particular action method shown above only seems to return a single `vote` to the page, so in that case there's nothing to count. Perhaps your viewmodel has to be different? It doesn't entirely make sense to ask about displaying the number of votes per answer when the model which is going back to the page for display is just a single vote.

Comment: Are you sure you sample code is correct? Because all your condition into your queries will always return true. e.g. a.Id == a.Id

Comment: Are you sure you aren't intending to return the Question back to the view, so you can display all the answers given for that question, and then display the number of votes given for each answer?

Comment: @ADyson Yeah probably sending the Question model to the view is better... But can you make a sample code to count each votes per answer ?

Comment: Assuming the model is of type `Question`, then in the View you can loop through `Model.Answers` with a `foreach answer in Model.Answers` and within the loop, for every answer you can print `answer.Votes.Count()` as I already described. It's not complex logic - it's just to loop through a collection and display a value from it.

Comment: you also need to fix the database code in your action method above so it just returns the right Question. Or perhaps you want to display results for all questions at once? I don't know, it's not really clear.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer so if it works I will accept it ? just not to leave the post on open

Comment: @ADyson I want to show voted answers for each questions

Comment: Ok so in that situation the model must instead be `IEnumerable<Question>` or `List<Question>` and then you loop through the question list, then within that loop through the answers list for that question and display the vote count. So one extra loop, that's all. I think you really could figure that out for yourself, with reference to generic online samples or documenation regarding foreach loops in Razor. But if not then let me know and I can post a full answer when there's time.

Comment: @ADyson I will try to do it on my own, but when you have time please add an answer so I can confirm that I made this the correct way

Comment: you can mostly confirm it by testing your code to see if it works as you intended, but ok.

Comment: @Adyson still can't manage to do it..

Comment: @ADyson i've already made it, but how can I do a graph for it?

Comment: you mean a graphical chart? Lots of ideas if you google it, this answer contains a few links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430701/drawing-charts-into-asp-net-mvc-4-razor-c-web-sites

Comment: @ADyson I'm having some trouble in interpretating how to do it ..

Comment: Edit the question (or maybe ask a new one) to show your new model, your view code so far and what problem you're having exactly. "Having trouble" doesn't give me much clue about what you're struggling with. Also you'd have to show some sample data and then a diagram of how you want the chart to display that data. (i.e....some requirements!)

Comment: @ADyson my problem right now is not understanding on how to do it ahha

Comment: Well firstly which tool are you going to use? Maybe start with the MS chart helper. Follow the guide at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart with the static example data. Get that working, and then all you have to do is replace the static data with data from your model. If you're not sure which data from your model you'll need to put into each section, you'll maybe have to play around with it. But first try to understand the chart concept, what the axes represent etc, and then hopefully it should become obvious what data you need.

Comment: The other answer on that question i linked (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28494837/5947043) also has some good examples. Follow an example. Then try to modify it. Then if you get stuck, that would be a good time to ask an SO question about it. We cannot spend the time to interpret the documentation for you in every tiny detail, you have to try and understand at least some of it for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
    <h4>Vote</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        @Model.Text

        @foreach (var answer in Model.Answers)
        {
            <br />
            <label>
                @answer.Text:   @answer.Votes.Count();
            </label>
        }
    </dl>
</div>
```